# Is updating npm after installing node recommended?

Tags: node.js, npm

After installing node via nvm I normally also update npm to the newest version. It this actually a recommended practice? Or should I use the npm version which is installed with node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The npm team recommends doing an `npm install -g npm` after installing Node. (In other words, they recommend updating to the latest stable `npm`.) See, for example, [this npm blog post](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/85484771375/how-to-install-npm).